Trading view Pinescript custom candle colors
I am trying to color Tradingview candles to be a bit more informative about the price action.  I have the conditions coded, but then creating the actual formula for the color, is a bit unknown to me from what I have read.  How do I code the color logic statement?
// Set the minimum custom range value
userDefinedRange = input(100, title="Custom Range") // Minimum custom range value set to 100 points

// Calculate Candle inputs
candleRange = high - low
candleBody = math.abs(open-close)
// Determine relationship between open and close for bullish and bearish candles
isBullishClose = close > close[1]
isBearishClose = close < close[1]
isBuying = close > open
isSelling = close < open
isNothing = math.abs(close / close[1] - 1) < 0.001

bullish = isBullishClose and isBuying
bullishselling = isBullishClose and isSelling
nothing = isNothing
bearishbuying = isBearishClose and isBuying
bearish = isBearishClose and isSelling

// Initialize color variables for bullish and bearish candles
bullishColor = color.green
bearishColor = color.red
nothingColor = color.blue
bearishbuyingColor = color.purple
bullishsellingColor = color.teal

// Change candle color based on custom range input in real-time
candleColor = userDefinedRange ? (bullish ? bullishColor : bearishColor) : na

// Plot Colored Candles based on custom range input
plotcandle(open, high, low, close, color=candleColor, wickcolor=candleColor)


your code looks fine https://i.imgur.com/XR9csgX.png
